# How to remove bonds between specific atoms in VMD

Tags: lammps, vmd

I have an .xyz file containing an alumina surface and a water box placed above the surface. I am trying to setup a LAMMPS calculation using CLAYFF, and I need to remove bonds between Al and O atoms, and the corresponding Al-O-Al and O-Al-O terms. From the [documentation for Topotools](https://sites.google.com/site/akohlmey/software/topotools/documentation) I found that it is possible to remove bonds between individual atoms. I can technically brute force removing the bonds and the angles, but I would like a cleaner solution for this problem. If there are any commands that can automatically do this transformation in VMD, that would solve my problem.

Comment: You can probably try with the atom selection to target the Al and O atoms and use `topo delbond` and `topo delangle` to remove bonds and angles.

Comment: I tried that, but the ```topo delbond``` command requires two integers (which are the atom ids)

Comment: You can loop through the atom IDs for Al and O.

Comment: That would be brute forcing it. I had already considered it, and was looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why not do it in LAMMPS, creating a group that contains the relevant atoms, using `delete_bonds` to remove the bonds, and then `write_data` to write out the new configuration?